# Delayed Job drives memory usage to 100%

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, delayed-job

I'm using "Delayed Job" for years but I'm stuck with a memory usage.

When I'm uploading a lot a files, jobs do their job as usual according to the queue. My memory is more used at this time obviously. But when it's done, memory usage still goes up to be stuck at 100%.. Until a restart the jobs (which are currently 4).

Is there any obvious reason that I don't know to not release memory after having done a job?

I don't know if it's linked to those jobs of to Paperclip's jobs.

I'm using:

```
Rails (4.2.0)
ruby (2.2.1)
delayed_job (4.0.6)
delayed_job_active_record (4.0.3)
delayed_paperclip (2.9.1)
```

Comment: not directly related to issue, but I also had problems with DJ and switched to Sidekiq quite some time ago. The migration is not hard to do, but Sidekiq's performance is much better, and it is super-less-less problematic. Especially after the upgrade to 4.0 it is just awesome (not to mention speed up)